# Distribute Ruby on Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, software-distribution

I'm trying to figure out a way to distribute a Rails application in a fairly standalone way. Think of [Sickbeard](http://sickbeard.com/) or [CouchPotato](https://couchpota.to/), two apps you only need Python to run.

That's basically what I want to achieve, but with Rails instead. There are some failure stories out there and some that are just too complicated, but I'm hoping that there has been some advancements in the field that I just can't find.

Is there a way to distribute a Rails application including any gems it depends on in a way you only require Ruby installed to run it?

I have no intention of trying to obfuscate the source code.

Answer (score 0):

Just use Bundler. Mostly every new Ruby installation have RubyGems and Bundler in standard so the only thing that End-User should do is:

```
$ bundle install
$ rails s
```

And will get running app with all dependencies installed.

Comment: While I kind of wanted to skip the bundler dependency, I suppose you have a point.

Comment: There is no way because you have at least dependency on rails gem.

Comment: While true, wouldn't it be possible to bundle the required gems with the app? Installing them to a folder with bundler for example. Realised this just now, haven't had time to try it out yet.

Comment: @Frans  is it possible to bundle every dependency along with the app, so that just unzipping would make my app run without any additional dependency download?

Comment: Should be doable, but I never really tried enough to find out. For my own need I'm actually considering rebuilding this app with Electron instead; currently a native Windows program, which I'm not fond of.