# Distribute a Ruby on Rails Application with VMware

Tags: ruby-on-rails, vmware

The idea is to find an easy solution to distribute a rails application with dependencies (redis, database, apache etc)

It seems that Github does a good job on this, see [github-enterprise-faq](https://enterprise.github.com/faq). The idea is to pack the rails app as an VMware to hide the code and mount it to the network.

Does anybody have experience with that approach?

similar to, but old:

- 2012 [Distribute Ruby on Rails app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12484213/distribute-ruby-on-rails-app)
- 2008 [Can you Distribute a Ruby on Rails Application without Source?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/99553/can-you-distribute-a-ruby-on-rails-application-without-source)
- [Options for distribution of an offline Ruby on Rails application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55711/options-for-distribution-of-an-offline-ruby-on-rails-application)

Answer (score 0):

[Vagrant](https://www.vagrantup.com/) and [Chef](https://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/provisioning/chef_solo.html) are exactly what you're after.

Comment: yes, good one. chef is a bit too much, becuase i do not want to do the server setup by myself. i also had a look into docker.com which seems also an alternative to VMware. but it says on the website: "complete development environment". distribution == production